# Fill HTML-textfield-value with PHP $_GET-parameter

Tags: php, html, input, get, textfield

I have a link like this:

```
/index.php?textfieldvalue=test123
```

This link navigates to a site with a textfield. If this site is opened, the default-value should be "test123". To do this i used the PHP $_GET-parameter "textfieldvalue".

My textfield looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php $_GET('textfieldvalue') ?>" required />
```

But the textfield is still empty....

(And $_GET('target') is not empty! I printed it for testing seperate out)

Comment: What is that 'target' ? it's should be 'textfieldvalue' ? also remove & between ?

Comment: try with this - `<input type="text" value="<?php $_GET['textfieldvalue'] ?>" required />`

Comment: you should remove '&' After '?'
and in input field `<input type="text" value="<?php $_GET['textfieldvalue'] ?>" required />`

Comment: Square brackets. That's all I have to say :)

Comment: Sorry, i put some type-errors in my example. Now my start-post is correct, but don't works!

Comment: You might want to escape that `_GET` value, to stop a potential XSS attack ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove '&' After '?' and in input field write:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['textfieldvalue'] ?>" required />
```